# Get actual facingMode of a mediaStreamTrack in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mediastream

I want to know the actual facingMode of a media stream track in order to invert (mirror) the image or not depending on whether the active camera is at the back or at the front of a device. If the actual facingMode is "user", the CSS property of the video will be: `transform: scaleX(-1)`; if the facingMode is "environment", I do not invert the image.

This is my piece of code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ facingMode: "environment", width: { ideal: 4096 } })
.then (function(mediaStream){
   video.srcObject = mediaStream;
   console.log('facingmode: ' + video.srcObject.getTracks()[0].getSettings().facingMode);
});
```

In Chrome, everything works as expected: The console shows "environment" or "user", depending on the actually active camera.

In Firefox, the console always shows "undefined" (what is not expected) (same behaviour on computer and on smartphone).

Could someone help me to retrieve the actual facingMode in Firefox too?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox for Android and other clients that still don't provide
[MediaTrackSettings.facingMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/facingMode), a workaround is to inspect the
[MediaStreamTrack.label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/label), e.g.:

```js
const isEnvironment =
  "environment" == video.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().facingMode
    || video.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].label.indexOf("acing back") !== -1;
```

Unfortunately, the [labels may vary](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#ref-for-dom-mediastreamtrack-label-2) across user agents.

The above snippet works in Firefox Mobile 68. Even in German, the label for the back camera is "Camera 0, Facing back, Orientation 90".

Answer (score 0):

Firefox can return the correct [facing mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/facingMode) without problem. I've test it using the following code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true})
.then(function(stream) {
  console.log(stream.getTracks()[0].getSettings().facingMode);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

The problem you have is maybe that you haven't authorized the page to use the camera. Go to `Preferences -> Permissions -> Camera -> Settings ...` and uncheck `Block new requests asking to access your camera`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you're answer, unfortunately, the box you mean is already unchecked. The getUserMedia() instruction actually asks for choosing a camera. On my smartphone, I can choose between the front and the back camera, then I can use the stream, ie displays the image on the page, but I cannot get the property "facingMode". Any other idea ?